# difference between eq and == in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

What is the difference, if any, between the keyword 'eq' and the operator '==' in JSP Expression Language?

In code, what is the difference between:

```
<c:if test="${var1 eq var2}">some code</c:if>
```

and

```
<c:if test="${var1 == var2}">some code</c:if>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`eq` exists (as well as `ne`, `lt`, etc) so you can avoid using XML entity references (< is an XML character and would need to be escaped as `&lt;`, for example), but they do the same thing.

See [Comparison operators in JSP](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=550) for more info.

Comment: Entirely correct, they're exactly the same. The characterbased operators are only XML-safe.