# Compare if BigDecimal is equal to zero in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl, bigdecimal

I am comparing a big decimal value in jsp like this,

`<fmt:formatNumber value="${totalAmount}" pattern="0.00" var="totalAmountApplied" />
<c:if test="${totalAmountApplied != '0'}" >` but some how it doesnt seem to work. Any idea on what am i missing here..

Comment: Possible Duplicate -->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765555/testing-if-a-bigdecimal-value-is-zero-in-a-jsp-el-expression

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't it be the textual string '0.00' you would compare with?
In that case, use !aString.equals(String) instead of !=